# (trim($file) shows unknown error

Tags: php, string

I try to code an little "grab infos from page X" - Script. i get an code from the internet, but its not working:

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in

```
$file = @fopen ($url,"r");
if (trim($file) == "")   <<<<errormessage belongs to here.
```

So i tried to check if `$file` isn't a string or not. PHP says:

not an string

not an INT

not an numeric

not an array

So what is it then? Applepie ? :D

How to fix this script to use it?

The whole script is as follows,

```
<?php
// URL, die durchsucht werden soll
$url = "http://xxxxxxxx/community/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxx/";

// Zeichenfolge vor relevanten EintrÃƒÂ¤gen

$startstring .= "<td class=\"td-minor\">";
$startstring1 .= "<td class=\"td-value\">";

// bis zum nÃƒÂ¤chsten html tag bzw. Zeichenfolge nach relevanten EintrÃƒÂ¤gen
$endstring = "</td>"; 

$file = @fopen ($url,"r");

if (trim($file) == "")
 {
  echo "Service out of order";
 } 
 else 
 {
  $i=0;
    while (!feof($file)) 
    {
     // Wenn das File entsprechend groÃƒÅ¸ ist, kann es unter UmstÃƒÂ¤nden
     // notwendig sein, die Zahl 2000 entsprechend zu erhÃƒÂ¶hen. Im Falle
     // eines Buffer-Overflows gibt PHP eine entsprechende Fehlermeldung aus.
     $zeile[$i] = fgets($file,2000);
     $i++;
    }
  fclose($file);
 }

// Nun werden die Daten entsprechend gefiltert.

for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) 
{
 if ($resa = strstr($zeile[$j],$startstring)) 
 {
  $resb = str_replace($startstring, "", $resa);
  $endstueck = strstr($resb, $endstring);
  $resultat .= str_replace($endstueck,"",$resb);
  $resultat .= ";";
 }
}

for ($k=0;$k<$i;$k++) 
{
 if ($resa = strstr($zeile[$k],$startstring1)) 
 {
  $resb = str_replace($startstring1, "", $resa);
  $endstueck = strstr($resb, $endstring);
  $resultat1 .= str_replace($endstueck,"",$resb);
  $resultat1 .= ";";
 }
}

// Ausgabe der Daten

$array_0 = explode(";",$resultat);
$array_1 = explode(";",$resultat1);

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array_0); $i++ ) 
 {
  echo "".$array_0[$i].$array_1[$i]."<br>";
 }

return $resultat;

?>
```

I just

```
$file = @fopen ($url,"r");
```

a URL.

Answer (score 1):

As the warning states it is a resource. Per the manual of fopen, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php,

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

You can use, `fread`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php. Which will read the resource.

You also could use `file_get_contents` in place of the `fopen` and `fread` pairing. `file_get_contents` returns a string by default.

So your code would be...

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
```

Also try to avoid use the `@` that is turning off useful messages.

Comment: Also `file` to get array of strings

Answer (score 0):

The `fopen()` function returns a resource, just like the error message states. If you only want the content, you can use [`file_get_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
if (trim($data) === "") {
    // stuff
}
```